# How can I show/hide a window with a hotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, window-management

I'm looking for a way to show/hide a window with a specific title. One example is when you press `win+1`, the first window at task bar will show, when you press again, it will be minimized.

I checked [this page](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/25473-toggle-hideshow-window/), but the methods they suggested are not working at my end.

Comment: Those are standard methods and should work if you correctly specify window title and /or class.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro thanks for your answer, it solved my question. Btw I'm using `ahk_group` now, meaning a hotkey can swap through same class of windows, e.g. all browser windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check whether a specific window has been minimized with [**WinGet**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm). (*[Credit to Laszlo](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/8529-how-to-find-out-if-window-is-minimized/?p=53590)*)

```
WinGet WinState, MinMax, %WinTitle%   ; Retrieve minimized/maximized state
```

You can then show or hide said window with [**WinMinimize**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMinimize.htm) and [**WinRestore**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinRestore.htm).

```
#m::WinMinimize, Untitled - Notepad   ; Minimize window to taskbar
#r::WinRestore, Untitled - Notepad    ; Unminimize or unmaximize window
```

The hotkey below checks a window's state, then minimizes or unminimizes the window.

```
#1::
   WinTitle := "Untitled - Notepad"
   WinGet WinState, MinMax, %WinTitle%  ; retrieve minimized/maximized state
      if (WinState = -1)                ; minimized
         WinRestore, %WinTitle%
      else                              ; not minimized
         WinMinimize, %WinTitle%
Return
```

**See Also**

- AHK Forums: [How to find out if window is minimized?](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/8529-how-to-find-out-if-window-is-minimized/)
- AHK Documentation: [WinMinimize](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMinimize.htm), [WinRestore](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinRestore.htm), [WinMaximize](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMaximize.htm)